# How does the database knows which sever to query for specific data

Tags: database, mongodb, postgresql, sharding

Lets say we have postgres and mongodb server and we sharded.

How does the database knows the specific database server to query a certain record.
or do we have to implement the logic in application layer

Does it differs for sql and no sql database

Comment: You shard for a specific database (MongoDB or PostgreSQL). You cannot combine them.  See [MongoDB Sharding](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/).

Comment: yes i know that i am talking about them separately

Answer (score 2):

databases are divided into two parts.
server and client.
you can have few installed servers on the same machine and even a few on another machine, but every time you wanna use a client you will have to connect to a specific server.
if you connect your app to some DB - your app will act as a client, so you will have to connect from your app to some specific server by specifying a network address and port number.

Answer (score 0):

Either your client/app server can decide which database server to direct the query to based on application-embedded logic, or you can have a coordinator node which your client connects to and which then routes the query as appropriate, based on look-up tables it keeps, and makes it all transparent to the client.

It is your hypothetical setup, we can't know what you did; you have to tell us.  Did you use some commercial or open-source add-on to implement this?

Comment: see i aint sharding a database am just asking this question out of curiosity.btw i dont think lookup tables are the norm because they can become point of failure

lets say i  have set up key based shard how would we know the server to query